# Trying to replace something inside a string that has parentheses, java

Tags: java

Hi I'm petty new to java and I have a question,

I'm trying to replace the String " 22(S)" with " 22(I)" but for some reason the replace first doesn't replace the String.

Here is my code:

```
public class tes {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int y = 22;
    String x = " 22(S)";
    
    x = x.replaceFirst(" " + y + "(S)", " " + y + "(I)");                   

    System.out.println(x);

}
```

}

While I know that I can do x.replaceFirst("S","I") , I want to understand why this is still producing 22(S) with my current code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because `(` and `)` are grouping operators in *regular expression*. You need to escape them in the match term. Like,

```
x = x.replaceFirst(" " + y + "\\(S\\)", " " + y + "(I)");
```

And I get

```
 22(I)
```

with no other changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Replace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int y = 22;
        String x = " 22(S)";
        x = x.replaceAll(" " + y + "\\(S\\)", " " + y + "(I)");
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

By using `replaceAll` also we can replace all the S letters to I